# Math font in beamer not working like in article

Tags: beamer

I have a problem dealing with the math font in beamer.
I want the variables to be **positioned on top of the sigma sign**, but when I use fractions, it doesn't work although it works normally if there are no fractions.

Here is an example[image]

```
\begin{frame}{Optimization problem}
We arrive at the optimization problem
\begin{alignat}{3}
    &\argmin_{\theta} 
    &\quad  &   \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^N \big[u_i - u_{\mathrm{NN}}(x_i, t_i; \theta)\big]^2 } \\
    &\text{subject to} 
    &       &   u_{\mathrm{NN}, t}  + N(u_\mathrm{NN}) = 0
\end{alignat}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: If you really want the limits above and below the sum, type `\sum\limits` but that will make the denominator very tall without improving the look of the fraction.

Comment: Thanks. That worked!